# R Levels wrong on larger dataset

Tags: r

I have the following snippet that reads in set of data with roughly 900,000 rows. The Dates column comes in as a factor and I want to extract the hour so I can aggregate on it and do a barplot of the count of rows per hour.

I'm confused right now because when I inspect the 'd' dataframe which is a small subset, it has the correct levels for 'Hour' (i.e. 0,1,2,3,4,etc) but the 'df' dataframe reads "Factor w/ 1 level '0'". Since this is the same exact code, can someone explain to me what's wrong here?

The bar graph shows up perfectly fine for the 'd' dataframe but the 'df' dataframe just returns one bar (as expect based on the issue above).

Thank you!

```
df <- read.csv('train.csv')  
d <- df[1:1000,]  
d <- droplevels(d)  
df <- droplevels(df)  
d$Hour <- as.factor(hour(as.POSIXct(as.character(d$Dates))))  
df$Hour <- as.factor(hour(as.POSIXct(as.character(df$Dates))))
```

Comment: This can probably be solved by `read.csv('train.csv', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. Same result :(

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this was downvoted but after digging around quite a bit, there was one specific row that contained an issue with the Date coming in. While the format looked exactly the same, running as.POSIXlt/as.POSIXct on it always returned a datetime with the time dropped which resulted in the levels being thrown off. I had to specifically defined a timezone argument which ended up fixing the issue.